# Is there a way to load externaldata from a variable URL in Kusto?

Tags: kql

With Kusto's externaldata operator, I am able to load a text file from my website:

```
let appUsers = externaldata(userId:string)['https://www.mybusiness.com/files/salesforce-guid.txt'];
```

However I need to manipulate the URL string based on differing factors. When I try moving the URL into a variable, Kusto gives me syntax errors ( *expected ']'* )

```
let url = 'https://www.mybusiness.com/files/salesforce-guid.txt';
let appUsers = externaldata(userId:string)[url]; // syntax err
```

Is there a way for Kusto to load externaldata from a variable URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such functionality doesn't exist.

You can suggest it on https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice